# Angular 2 ngModel in child component updates parent component property

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I made a simple UI which consist two components (parent and child).

What the UI does is that when I type some stuff in the input box of the Child component. The value will change using ngModel.

The child component works fine that way.

```
// Child Component
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <p>{{sharedVar}}</p>
        <input [(ngModel)]="sharedVar">
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    sharedVar: string;
}
```

Now I have a parent component which I intend to use the same value as Child Component.

I added the Child Component into the Parent template, and use dependency injection to call Child Component's `sharedVar`.

```
// Parent Component
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <h1>{{sharedVar}}</h1>
        <child></child>
    `,
    directives: [ChildComponent],
    providers: [ChildCompnent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    sharedVar: string;
    constructor(child: ChildComponent) {
        this.sharedVar = child.sharedVar;
    }
}
```

The problem is as I'm typing in the input box, the value in `<p>` changes automatically while the value in parent component's `<h1>` do not change.

Comment: Don't inject components, you pass values to children components using `@Input` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html, the instance created by the template and the instance you create by specifying a provider are two different instances.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

We can use the `[(x)]` syntax in the parent template to achieve two-way databinding with the child.  If we create an Output property with the name `xChange`, Angular will automatically update the parent property.  We do need to `emit()` an event whenever the child changes the value however:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <p>Child sharedVar: {{sharedVar}}</p>
        <input [ngModel]="sharedVar" (ngModelChange)="change($event)">
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() sharedVar: string;
    @Output() sharedVarChange = new EventEmitter();
    change(newValue) {
      console.log('newvalue', newValue)
      this.sharedVar = newValue;
      this.sharedVarChange.emit(newValue);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <div>Parent sharedVarParent: {{sharedVarParent}}</div>
        <child [(sharedVar)]="sharedVarParent"></child>
    `,
    directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    sharedVarParent ='hello';
    constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTQ0KXGqpbY5ba6VPvQO?p=preview)</kbd>

I used `sharedVarParent` in the ParentComponent just to demonstrate that the names don't have to be the same in the parent and child.

Comment: Now this is just pure gold. This information should be in official documentation in Cookbook/Component Interaction section on angular.io website.

Comment: Amazing! However, the updates weren't happing in my parent at first. Apparently it's very important that the var name of the @Output() event is the exact same as the input var but with 'Change' behind it. Is this described somewhere by Angular?

Comment: @deadconversations, yes, it is mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel) -- scroll down to the second green-bar note.

Comment: This is how documentation should be. Not 5 walls of text to get basically the same information.

Comment: If parent component have used the variable in *ngFor ,it is not getting updated .

Comment: Those who are looking for documentation https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Comment: How does affects when the parent has a form tag and by default enforces any input to have a name set when is binded to a model and the fact that the child component does not recognize when it is a form tag in a parent component?

Comment: This seems like what I need to fix my problem but I have no idea what is going on here... *sigh* (and I cant get it to work on my side)

Comment: And what if you need to emit two properties to parent? It says it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You could set up event emitter communication (`outputs`) from child to parent. For example like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: `
        <p>Child: {{sharedVar}}</p>
        <input [(ngModel)]="sharedVar" (ngModelChange)="change()">
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output() onChange = new EventEmitter();
    sharedVar: string;
    change() {
        this.onChange.emit({value: this.sharedVar});
    }
}
```

and the in parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <h1>{{sharedVar}}</h1>
        <child (onChange)="sharedVar = $event.value"></child>
    `,
    directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    sharedVar: string;
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/T2KH4nGKPSy6GEvbF1Nb?p=info

Comment: He's already using the shortcut of @Output with the two way binding. He's just overriding its own component by using `providers: [ChildCompnent]`. This is simpler imo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qo0dMzDf9HeSGHnwhl2d?p=preview

Comment: @Langley, I don't see parent property `sharedVar` changing in your plunker.  I think we have to `emit()` an event to get changes up to the parent.

Comment: You can simplify this approach by using `[(sharedVar)]` in the parent template, and then naming your output property `sharedVarChange`.  See my answer for details if interested.

Comment: @MarkRajcok you are right, I tought the label was in the parent and the input in the child, looks like it only works that way if you send the whole object, I changed the example to show the way I meant. It should be working now. In some scenarios, probably most, yours would be a better approach though.

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to have multiple two-way databindings in the same component, you can do

```
export class ComponentName {
    @Input() public first: string = '';
    @Input() public second: string = '';
    @Output() public firstChange = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() public secondChange = new EventEmitter();

    public functionName1(first: string): void {
        this.first = first;
        this.firstChange.emit(first);
    }

    public functionName2(second: string): void {
        this.second = second;
        this.secondChange.emit(second);
    }
}
```

When input and output are named 'x' and 'xChange', it detects them automatically in the parent belonging together.

I think this is actually a better practice than the one in the accepted answer, because here it makes immediately clear how the names are related.