# Angular2 how to pass reference for ngModel binding

Tags: binding, angular, web-component

I wrote this component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'formfield',
    template: `
        <div>
            <label>{{label}}</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model">
            </div>
        </div>
`
})
export class Formfield {
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() model: string;
}
```

I use it here:

```
<formfield label="something" model="somevalue"></formfield>
```

Not surprisingly the input field shows the string "somevalue". How can I make it to hold the value of the variable somevalue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 ngModel in child component updates parent component property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327929/angular-2-ngmodel-in-child-component-updates-parent-component-property)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327929/angular-2-ngmodel-in-child-component-updates-parent-component-property

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following:

```
<formfield label="something" [model]="someprop"></formfield>
```

where `someprop` is a property of the component that uses the `formfield` component.

For example:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  someprop:string = 'some value';
}
```

Comment: This works just half way. A change on the input field only affects the value of model but not the value of someprop.

Comment: model is just an @Input property, I would need something like `@InputOutput () model`