# How to update value in nested ngModel components during initialisation?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I am trying to intialize the default value within a nested component but the native HTML element is never updated.

```
Root [(ngModel)]="value"  
  |-> Child [(ngModel)]="value"
    | -> native
```

I have tried already *constructor* and *ngOnInit*. *AfterViewInit* and *AfterViewChecked* throws an error, that there is a value manipulation after change detection.

root template:

```
<child name="child" [(ngModel)]="value"></child>
```

child template:

```
<select name="childSelect" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.tpl.html',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() _value: number;
    private _onTouchedCallback: () => void = null;
    private _onChangeCallback: (a: any) => void = null;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.value = 1;
        // this._value = 1; // no difference
    }

    get value(): number {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: number) {
        this._value = value;
        if (this._onChangeCallback !== null) {
            this._onChangeCallback(this._value);
        }
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this._onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }
```

I think I missed a small detail.

http://plnkr.co/edit/F9pfUQ50YPV5UPiH0kw7

Answer (score 1):

I think you can see this similar question: [Angular 2 ngModel in child component updates parent component property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35327929/4956569)

@Mark Rajcok most-voted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329533/4956569

You can achieve with the two-way binding offered by Angular:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

**Following your example...**

You can simply **use the [(x)] syntax in the parent template**, **instead of [(ngModel)]** to achieve two-way databinding with the child.

root template:

```html
<child name="child" [(x)]="value"></child>
```

Rename "x" with whatever you want (ie: "myProp", "myValue", "y"...)

**On the child**, you have to **create an Output property of type "EventEmitter" with the name xChange**, Angular will automatically update the parent property!

child component:

```js
@Output xChange = new EventEmitter();
```

For example: if you renamed "x" with "myProp" the Output property MUST be "myPropChange"

You then **need to emit() an event whenever the child changes the value**.

child component:

```js
valueChanged(value) {
   this.xChange.emit(value);
}
```

Call "valueChanged" into your "set value()"

```js
set value(value: number) {
   this._value = value;
   this.valueChanged(value);
   if (this._onChangeCallback !== null) {
      this._onChangeCallback(this._value);
   }
}
```