# Issue with template in sharedVar in angular

Tags: angular

I want to know if I need to implement this in template tag only

```
 template: ` <p>Child: {{sharedVar}}</p> 
 <input [(ngModel)]="sharedVar" 
  (ngModelChange)="change()">
```

...because in my component I have

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction',
  templateUrl: './transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction.component.scss', ],

  })
```

like this. Can I implement it in my html directly

I referred it from -

[Angular 2 ngModel in child component updates parent component property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327929/angular-2-ngmodel-in-child-component-updates-parent-component-property)

Comment: You can't use both `templateUrl` and `template` in same component. You've to use either `templateUrl` or `template`.  The difference is in case of`templateUrl`, you write `html template` outside of  `.ts` file and in case of `template`, you write `html template` as string inside of `.ts`. Otherwise, there is nothing difference else

Comment: yes it will work you need to insert it in   'transaction.component.html' and also you have to import import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use both property in one component use either `templateUrl` or `template` Beacuse `template` is inline editing and `templateUrl` is html page inside editing. So you have to choose one only.