# Angular5 - Change parent's property from child component's input's [(ngModel)] binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327929/angular-2-ngmodel-in-child-component-updates-parent-component-property) similar question without success. The plunker mentioned in the question seems to be broken.

I am trying to update parent component's property from child component's [(ngModel)] binding.

This is the child components HTML:

```
<div class="elastic-textarea">
    <ion-input rows="1"  [value]="inputValue" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" ></ion-input>
    </div>
```

This is the child components TS:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-childinput',
  templateUrl: './childinput.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./childinput.component.css']
})
export class ChildinputComponent  {
@Input() inputValue: string;
  @Output() emitInputValue = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

change(newValue) {
    console.log('newvalue', newValue)
    this.inputValue = newValue;
    this.emitInputValue.emit(newValue);
  }
}
```

This is how I'm using the child component in the parent component:

```
<app-childinput [(inputValue)]="thevalue" ></app-childinput>
<p>The changed value should be reflected here: {{thevalue}}</p>
```

Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nspyip?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) demonstrating the issue. The parent component is the page callled "home", and the child component is the component called "childinput."

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not possible anymore in Angular?

Comment: `inputValue` marked with Input decorator, it should be used as `[inputValue]="thevalue`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `emitInputValue` to `inputValueChange`.

[Fixed Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bs7cgy?file=components/childinput/childinput.component.ts)

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able to. But seriously?! The event emmiters name has got to be the same as @Input name, but with "Change" attached to its end? :D Why and is it documented anywhere at all?

Comment: @gfels yeah since the `Input` and `Output` are defined in the same scope, they chose this naming rule to be able to recognize an `EventEmitter` used for custom two-way databinding. You can find some documentation here: https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-create-your-own-two-way-data-binding-in-angular-46487650ea82. Thank you in advance for the answer acceptance ;)

Answer (score 2):

childinput.component.html

```
<div class="elastic-textarea">
    <ion-input rows="1"  [value]="inputValue" [ngModel]="inputValue" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" ></ion-input>
</div>
```

home.html and home.ts
change

```
<app-childinput [(inputValue)]="thevalue" ></app-childinput>
```

to

```
<app-childinput [inputValue]="thevalue" (emitInputValue)="update($event)" ></app-childinput>


update(event) {
    this.thevalue = event;
  }
```

You declared Output EventEmitter `emitInputValue`,  you didn't emit it properly. `[(ngModel)]` is two way binding which you mixed it with your Input decorator `inputValue`

[image]